# Docker script permissions on Openshift

Tags: docker, permissions, dockerfile, openshift

I'm trying to run my own Azure build agent on Openhshift.
For this I'm following Microsoft's own instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#linux

Locally (on a arm64 Mac) everything will run fine. But when I build for x64 and deploy it to OpenShift (8.11) the start.sh won't run properly. Even though the script runs under root (confirmed by outputting id) it still runs into permission issues.

With the script unchanged the first error is when trying to write a variable to a (.token) file. This I resolved by chmodding the work dir in the Dockerfile.
The next issue is in the tar command which results in:

```
tar: .: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: .: Cannot change mode to rwsr-sr-t: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

What else can I do to prevent these permission issues when the script already runs as root?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to run a self-hosted agent on Openshift.
You actually don't need to give root permissions to the container for this case.

The way i fixed it was to add some permissions for the folder /azp.

Add these after the `COPY ./start.sh` statement on the Dockerfile and rebuild.

```bash
RUN chgrp -R 0 /azp && \
    chmod -R g=u /azp && \ 
    chmod 775 start.sh
```

The logic behind it is that Openshift will run the containers using an arbitrarily used user ID, and the group ID must be set to the root group (0). They also need to be read/writable by that groups as recommended by the OpenShift Container Platform-specific guidelines.

Since the container will not run as root on OpenShift, but will have an arbitrary  user ID then we modify the permissions to execute files with the `chmod 775 start.sh` command.

Let me know if this helps.